# How to use the respective php version name prior to composer

Tags: bash, magento, composer-php

I try to install an extension using the composer:

```
composer require magenest/module-worldpay-and-subscriptions:2.0.0
```

And get this:

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Package magenest/module-worldpay-and-subscriptions at version 2.0.0 has a PHP requirement incompatible with your PHP version (5.4.45)
```

When I run the `php -v` command it returns:

```
PHP 5.4.45 (cli) (built: Nov 28 2017 10:34:31)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v10.0.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.5, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
```

However, I have all PHP version installed on my server so when I run a command I usually specify the PHP version beforehand, e.g. `php-7.0 bin/magento`

Also, when using `fakechroot` - it has PHP version set within the context of the domain group itself. e.g when I run this command: `/usr/bin/fakechroot /usr/sbin/chroot /microcloud/domains/vampm2 /bin/bash` and then `php -v` I get:

```
[http]$ /usr/bin/fakechroot /usr/sbin/chroot /microcloud/domains/vampm2 /bin/bash
bash-4.1$ php -v
PHP 7.0.26 (cli) (built: Dec 19 2017 17:26:19) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v10.0.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.26, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
bash-4.1$ exit
```

Can anyone tell me how can I run the `composer require` without composer to read the default PHP 5.4? Working on **Magento ver 2.1.8**

How can I run the composer in specified version e.g. like I do with Magento `php-7.0 bin/magento`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three options:

1. Run `composer` with another PHP version, eg. through `php-7.0 $(which composer)`
2. Add distinct version requirements to your `composer.json` through a config key like `"platform": { "php": "7.0.12" }` (see https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform for more details)
3. Run `composer` with the flag `--ignore-platform-reqs` to ignore platform requirements completely. Then whatever you require is installed, without any check for installed PHP versions or extensions